# Crash sometimes deleting row at UITableView (only in iOS7)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I had my app running cool in `iOS6`, but when I updated for `iOS7` with the same code I was working with, I get this error when I try to delete a row in a table :

```
UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:
```

the following code like that

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        PACallLog *aLog = _logs[indexPath.row];
        [[PAFMDBManager sharedManager] deleteACallLog:aLog];
        [_logs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

In the `viewDidAppear` method,logs(array) get values from db,so when I delete the row,I should 
1.delete data from db
2.delte object from logs
3.execute `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method

But sometimes I get crash when I delete the row(only in `IOS7`)
can anybody help me?

Crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3065ae7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a9b76c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3065ad50 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x310030aa -[NSAssertionHandler         handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
4   UIKit                           0x32fdc8ce -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:] + 350
5   UIKit                           0x32fe020e -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingHeadersAndFooters] + 5278
6   UIKit                           0x32fda7d6 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 182
7   UIKit                           0x32fda286 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 1358
8   UIKit                           0x32fb2392 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8014
9   2cu                             0x00137a14 0x4000 + 1260052
10  UIKit                           0x32fd87c2 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 90
11  UIKit                           0x32fd8754 -[UITableViewCell _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 60
12  UIKit                           0x32e13d9e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
13  UIKit                           0x32e13d3a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 34
14  UIKit                           0x32e13d0e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 42
15  UIKit                           0x32dff73e -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
16  UIKit                           0x32e13756 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
17  UIKit                           0x32e13420 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
18  UIKit                           0x32e0e44c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 828
19  UIKit                           0x32de3d74 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
20  UIKit                           0x32de2564 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7112
```

Comment: Can you please paste exact crash report?

Comment: please put the crash log in the post so that we can tell you the problem and solution to it.

Comment: sure, I'll update the error log

Answer (score 0):

you can reload the tableview once again after deleting the rows. add this statement in your code.
[tableview reloaddata];

Comment: of course,I can use the reload tableview,but I lost the animation of delete a cell

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        PACallLog *aLog = _logs[indexPath.row];
        [[PAFMDBManager sharedManager] deleteACallLog:aLog];
        [_logs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        // Refill your array and table reload

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IT"S WORKING
at the end of  your commitEditingStyle method add this line this will help you to solve.

```
[TableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```